# BubbleSort swap intermittently works

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems sometimes this call to swap works and sometimes the return data doesn't change the array.

It seems to work with the smaller array but not the bigger one.

```
data = [1, 4, 5, 3, 2]

data = [1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 88, 92, 68, 22, 7,
        6, 11, 44, 56, 99, 31, 32, 66, 55,
        44, 77, 92, 24, 27, 14, 17, 18, 51,
        69, 61, 51, 82, 84, 14, 15, 60, 70]

def Swap(a, b):
    temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp

    return {a, b}

def BubbleSort(data):
  for i in range(0, len(data)-1):
    for j in range(0, len(data)-1):
      if data[j] > data[j+1]:
        (data[j], data[j+1]) = Swap(data[j], data[j+1])
    print("In data: ", data)

print("Before data: ", data)
BubbleSort(data)
print("After data: ", data)
```

Comment: `{a, b}` is a set; sets are unordered, so the order they will be assigned in is inconsistent. Try `return (a, b)` instead.

Comment: Try not returning a set. You can use a,b=b,a

Comment: there is no need for function you can simply do swap inline `(data[j], data[j+1]) = (data[j + 1], data[j])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Swap` function returns a *set*, the order of which is unspecified ( implementation-defined). You probably want to return a tuple (`return (a, b)` or, omitting the redundant parentheses, `return a, b`).

But the function is unnecessary anyway. The canonical way for swapping two values in Python is

```
a, b = b, a
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Swap` function returns a set, which has no defined order. Therefore, it is not guaranteed that it actually has the effect of swapping two items.

You probably meant to return a tuple, which is written as `(a, b)` or simply `a, b`.

Also, it is not necessary in Python to use a temporary variable to swap two values, due to tuple assignment.

The canonical way to write a swap function in Python is:

```
def swap(a, b):
    return b, a
```

Note also the lower-case function name which follows the official PEP-8 style guide.